# Mostrar datos en un ListView desde una base de datos

Tags: java, android, json, listview

Estoy decodificando el response en *JSON*, y quiero mostrar esos datos en un `ListView`, ¿ como puedo hacer esta tarea? . Les dejo mi avance.

```
public void onResponse(String response) {

                    System.out.println("INFORMACIÓN OBTENIDA DE LA BASE DE DATOS:");
                    //Crear un Objeto JSON a partir del string response
                    Object jsonObject = JSONValue.parse(response.toString());
                    //Convertir el objeto JSON en un array
                    JSONArray array = (JSONArray) jsonObject;

                    ArrayList<Usuarios> list = new ArrayList();

                    List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

                    //Iterar el array y extraer la información
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
                        JSONObject row = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
                        String nombre = row.get("usuario").toString();
                        String conexion= row.get("conexion").toString();
                        System.out.println("Usuario: " + nombre + " || 
                        Conexion: " + conexion);

                        al.add(nombre);
                        al.add(conexion);
                    }
                    ListView d = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
                }
```

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: Tienes los datos en un ArrayList y tu ListView, solo necesitas crear un Adapter con los datos obtenidos, para configurarlo a tu ListView, agregué respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teniendo tus datos en un `ArrayList`:

```
 List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
```

y teniendo la instancia del ListView, puedes llenar tu ListView primeramente creando un Adapter con los datos obtenidos:

```
//Crea Adapter.
ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, al);
```

y posteriormente configurar este Adapter a tu ListView,

```
  //Configura Adapter al ListView.  
  d.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

agrego código:

```
   ...
   ...
  //Iterar el array y extraer la información
                for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
                    JSONObject row = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
                    String nombre = row.get("usuario").toString();
                    String conexion= row.get("conexion").toString();
                    System.out.println("Usuario: " + nombre + " || 
                    Conexion: " + conexion);

                    al.add(nombre);
                    al.add(conexion);
                }
                ListView d = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

              //Crea Adapter con datos obtenidos.
              ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, al);  

              //Configura Adapter al ListView.  
               d.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Te recomiendo que en lugar de tener `nombre` y `conexion` en diferente celda puedas agregar los 2 en la misma:

```
//al.add(nombre);
//al.add(conexion);
al.add(nombre + " " + conexion);
```

---

Agrego un articulo que contiene un ejemplo [Ejemplo de Android ListView](http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/android-listview.php)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias! Anduvo de maravilla!

Comment: Excelente Santiago! saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Siendo `list` la lista que quieres que aparezca en el `ListView`:

```
.
.
.
ListView d = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list.toArray(new String[0]));
d.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
```